# How to convert deeply nested array with one object to object in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

The requirement is to convert all `sales` array properties to objects with their first elements' quantity value. The collection name is `branches` and the example data is below.

```
[
{
    "_id": 111,
    "recs": [
        {
            "date": "01-01-2021",
            "sales": [
                {
                    "quantity": {
                        "P": 14,
                        "K": 0,
                        "U": 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "02-01-2021",
            "sales": [
                {
                    "quantity": {
                        "P": 23,
                        "K": 0,
                        "U": 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": 21,
    "recs": [
        {
            "date": "01-01-2021",
            "sales": [
                {
                    "quantity": {
                        "P": 11,
                        "K": 0,
                        "U": 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "02-01-2021",
            "sales": [
                {
                    "quantity": {
                        "P": 31,
                        "K": 0,
                        "U": 0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

The expected response is below.

```
[
{
    "_id": 111,
    "recs": [
        {
            "date": "01-01-2021",
            "sale": {
                "P": 14,
                "K": 0,
                "U": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried `$map`, `$addFields` but no way I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `$map`, you need:

1. `$first` to query the first `sales.quantity` object in `recs.sales` array.
2. `$mergeObject` to merge the current document in `recs` array with the document from (1).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      recs: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$recs",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                sales: {
                  $first: "$$this.sales.quantity"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4eiesuq1Rpr)

Comment: It works like a charm. I really appreciate you. Lastly, I'm just asking because I'm curious, Is it possible to make the same thing with `$arrayToObject` ?

Comment: Hi, I think `$arrayToObject` is not suitable for this case.